# Remote video not display using webrtc scaledrone

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Hi can someone check is there something wrong with my code cause it not displayig the remote video. The log always return 'Start web RTC as 'offerer'' for both local and remote video. And I think mostly the sample code almost similar with my code so I dont know. Much love appreciate if you guys can help me. Thanks!

```
 if (!location.hash) {
  location.hash = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
}
const roomHash = location.hash.substring(1);
//const roomHash = '5dfd9b';
console.log("ROOM ID: >> " +roomHash);

// TODO: Replace with your own channel ID
const drone = new ScaleDrone('AUpfMxm16E9bfdgA');
// Room name needs to be prefixed with 'observable-'
//const roomName = 'observable-' + roomHash;
const roomName = 'observable-testPHR';
const configuration = {
  iceServers: [{
    urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
  }]
};
let room;
let pc;


function onSuccess() {
    console.log("Connection sucess");
};
function onError(error) {
  console.log("Connection failed!");
  //console.error(error);
};

drone.on('open', error => {

  if (error) {
     console.log( " Error open drone >>");
    return console.error(error);
  }
  console.log(" Drone open >>")
  room = drone.subscribe(roomName);
  room.on('open', error => {
    if (error) {
      onError(error);
    }
  });

  // We're connected to the room and received an array of 'members'
  // connected to the room (including us). Signaling server is ready.
  room.on('members', members => {
    console.log('MEMBERS', members);
    // If we are the second user to connect to the room we will be creating the offer
    const isOfferer = members.length === 2;
    startWebRTC(isOfferer);
  });
});

// Send signaling data via Scaledrone
function sendMessage(message) {
    console.log("Sending signal via scaledrone >>");
  drone.publish({
    room: roomName,
    message
  });
}

function startWebRTC(isOfferer) {
  console.log('Starting WebRTC in as', isOfferer ? 'offerer' : 'waiter');
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

  console.log(" Test A ");
  // 'onicecandidate' notifies us whenever an ICE agent needs to deliver a
  // message to the other peer through the signaling server
  pc.onicecandidate = event => {
    console.log("Send Message to Candidate");
    if (event.candidate) {
      sendMessage({'candidate': event.candidate});
    }
  };

  console.log(" Test B ");
  // If user is offerer let the 'negotiationneeded' event create the offer
  if (isOfferer) {
      console.log(" Create Offer ");
    pc.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      pc.createOffer().then(localDescCreated).catch(onError);
    }
  }

  console.log(" Test C ");
  // When a remote stream arrives display it in the #remoteVideo element
  pc.ontrack = event => {
    console.log("Display remote video >>>")
    const stream = event.streams[0];
    console.log(" Stream : >>" +stream);
    if (!remoteVideo.srcObject || remoteVideo.srcObject.id !== stream.id) {
      remoteVideo.srcObject = stream;
    }
  };

  console.log(" Test D ");

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  }).then(stream => {
    console.log(" Display Local Video >> ");
    // Display your local video in #localVideo element
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    // Add your stream to be sent to the conneting peer
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
  }, onError);

 console.log(" Test E ");
  // Listen to signaling data from Scaledrone
  room.on('data', (message, client) => {
    // Message was sent by us
    if (client.id === drone.clientId) {
      return;
    }

console.log(" Test F ");

    if (message.sdp) {
      // This is called after receiving an offer or answer from another peer
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.sdp), () => {
        // When receiving an offer lets answer it
        if (pc.remoteDescription.type === 'offer') {
          console.log(" Answer call ");
          pc.createAnswer().then(localDescCreated).catch(onError);
        }
      }, onError);
    } else if (message.candidate) {
      // Add the new ICE candidate to our connections remote description
      pc.addIceCandidate(
        new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate), onSuccess, onError
      );
    }

  });
}

function localDescCreated(desc) {
  pc.setLocalDescription(
    desc,
    () => sendMessage({'sdp': pc.localDescription}),
    onError
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please print your remote stream SDP and add in your question.

Comment: hi @Daljeet, its okay it works now. I just change 'pc.ontrack' to 'pc.onaddstream'. But i'm facing another porblem which is its not working on mobile browser. Do you know why? I mean if android <-> android its not working, but if dekstop <-> android it works well.